# Use Sql like operator in tJava Talend

Tags: java, sql, talend

I have two questions :

1- I want to use a regular expression in the tJava component, I extract a field from the database then I check if it is in this format:

F0 * 0 * -03 * the stars represent a character

I did this in sql with the following query:

```
select * from sales where product like ''F0_0_-03_'
```

How can I do this with a tJava?

2. - I get a field from the database and in output I declared this field in BIG DECIMAL

for example :

input: 4.00000000000000000

output: 4,000,000,000000

I want to have an output like 4,000000000000 with only one comma, I checked the separator option in my excel file (tFileOutputExcel)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4a6UD.png)

Comment: please create 2 posts if you have 2 questions. It would be better for people looking for this kind of questions.

Answer (score 0):

You dont't need to use a tJava component to check if a value is in the right format. You can use a tMap expression for that.

```
source.field.matches("^F0.0.-03.$") ? field.value : ""
```

It looks like your Talend version doesn't support setting the Decimal separator in tFileOutputExcel. The easiest way is to change it in the Excel options itself (Options > Advanced > uncheck Use system separators) and disable the thousands separator in tFileOutputExcel.